# Send a new header parameter to the server from a jsp page

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I have made first request via ajax to servlet "A"
I have set header in response from servlet "A" and returned some data.

Eg: response.setHeader("name", "Deva");
    out.println("success");

i got response now i am making second request from html page to servlet "A" via ajax.

now here my requirement is to get header information that i have set in response but my problem is how do i set header information to request.

The request object does not have the setHeader method and if I set it through the response object I am not able to get the value at the server.

Comment: To set an header to send to the client you have to use the Response object. And getting the value at the server should not be needed because you are setting the value at the server.

Comment: I want to send received header value to server back for validation pupose

Comment: You have to do that in the client. I assume you're using javascript with an ajax request so you have to add the header there.

Comment: It might be easier to use a cookie, those are send to and from the client automaticly

Comment: Okay.. thank you for suggestion. Actually i want to do this with header.